# How to insert string into plotting function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code that creates a histogram from my data using seaborn in python:

```
ax=sns.histplot(data=data, y=value, x=category)
            ax.figure.set_size_inches(7,len(10))
            plt.title('Title'.format(field))
            plt.show()
```

Now I want to work on creating a for loop that creates a different type of plot for my data from a list of data types. Specifically, for my data, I want to create a histogram, a boxplot, and violin plot from my data using seaborn.

And so, I have this list of seaborn plot types:

```
plot_type_list = ['histplot', 'boxplot', 'violinplot]
```

And so I want to loop through this list of plot types and try each plot type for my data. I try the following:

```
for plot_type in plot_type_list:
     ax=sns.plot_type(data=data, y=value, x=category)
          ax.figure.set_size_inches(7,len(10))
          plt.title('Title'.format(field))
          plt.show()
```

My reasoning here was that the "plot_type" in `sns.plot_type()` would be substituted by each string in my plot_type_list, thus creating each type of plot from my data. However, this code attempt returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plot_type_list'
```

I see that python is not inserting my plot_type string into the seaborn plotting function as I intended, rather just preserving "plot_type" as "plot_type", rather than "histplot", "boxplot", and "violinplot". How can I fix my code so that the seaborn plotting function has each plot type inserted, such that for through my for loop, I can create a histplot, boxplot, and violinplot?

Comment: where is your data? Please attach your data along with a post to get a better solution by community.

Comment: `getattr(sns, plot_type)(data=data, y=value, x=category)`

Comment: Try with replace `ax=sns.plot_type(data=data, y=value, x=category)` line with 
 `ax = eval("sns." + plot_type)(data=data, y=value, x=category)`

Comment: If it useful then you can mark as answer and upvote for other users who have similar problem in future. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe `for kind in ['hist','violin','box']:` with `sns.catplot(data=data, y=value, x=category, kind=kind, height=7, aspect=1.5)` works for you?  See [seaborn catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

Comment: A pythonic approach would be:  `for func in [sns.histplot, sns.violinplot, sns.boxplot]:` with `func(data=data, y=value, x=category)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's built-in `eval()` function.

You need to replace your line of code :

`ax=sns.plot_type(data=data, y=value, x=category)`

**with**

`ax = eval("sns." + plot_type)(data=data, y=value, x=category)`